# script in mvc razor editortemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using an editortemplate, I have shown partial code below.
The script tag repeats for each of the rows being rendered by the partial view.

Is there a way to get the script tag into the page header, or at the very least have it included in the page only once?

I would like the code in the partial view as that is where it truly belongs.

---

```
@* DisplayTemplates/contact.cshtml *@
@model Online.Web.Contacts.Contact

<script id="xxx">
  stuff here.
</script>

<tr>
   <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName)</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Online.Web.Contacts.Contact>
<script id="xxx">
  stuff here.
</script>
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

and then another editor template for a single contact:

```
@model Online.Web.Contacts.Contact
<tr>
   <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName)</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This could be an option, it just seems to fragmented. I am going to code three templates for each editable grid. I perhaps need to relook at it and do everything a different way.

Comment: @Jim, yes putting the script into the main view seems like a better option.

Comment: I am not happy with this - but it is the correct answer. I decided to factor things a completely different way.

Comment: @Jim: I have the same problem now... what is the best way to include javascript in a template, and not have it repeated all over the place?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. This is my 2c, but if the script isn't supposed to repeat, than the template isn't the right place?

How about using an [Html Helper](http://weblogs.asp.net/mikaelsoderstrom/archive/2010/10/06/declarative-helpers-in-razor.aspx)

Comment: using a helper could be an option. Is is possible to get the helper to add the script tag to the header somehow? What I am trying to do here is include a java script editing template in the row displaytemplate. The editing template belongs to the row. *not* to the model, so in that sense it is in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have a solution for this that seems to work reliably, at least in ASP.NET MVC3. Here's an excerpt from my address editor template:

```
@if(!Context.Items.Contains("AddressScriptsDone"))
{
    Context.Items.Add("AddressScriptsDone", "true");
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Address.js?" + _Config.WebAppVersion)"></script>
}
```

Context.Items seems to made for this purpose. It persists across multiple calls to the same EditorTemplate, but only for one complete page request.